# Capturing Touch Up Event in TextView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4

Is it possible?

Basically I want to show address of a restaurant. It could be in label or text view. However I need that label or text view to be multiline. Can I do so with label?

Also if user click on address they should be able to add the biz into their contact.

How would I do so because textView doesn't seem to capture any action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a label. `UILabel` supports multilines through the property `numberOfLines`. Say your address is in an `NSArray`. You can do this –

```
// address is the array
// addressLabel is the label that needs to be updated.

addressLabel.numberOfLines = [address count];
addressLabel.text = [address componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
```

This should do it. Make sure you have allocated a proper frame for this. If there are a lot of lines, you can consider putting it in a `UIScrollView`.

Comment: But Label doesn't support any action too. How do I know if a touch up event has happened on a label?

Comment: `addressLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;` should get you touches.

Comment: I check User Interaction Enabled in identity inspector. Then I go to connection inspector and I do not see touch up in send action'

Comment: I right drag (or control drag) from the label and textview to the code. IBAction doesn't even show up.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the uilabel's property called label.numberOfLines=someNumber;if you need any clarification ask me freely